# Cant convert Swift CMTimeRange to Float or get the number?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cmtime

Im having a data type issue - with AVPlayer in Swift I am given a CMTimeRange when I try to get:

```
AudioPlayerManager.shared.currentTrack?.playerItem?.loadedTimeRanges[0]
```

What is printed with this is:

```
Optional(CMTimeRange: {{0/1 = 0.000}, {1016722/600 = 1694.537, rounded}})
```

I have tried all the members and trying to get a value for the cmtimerange key here, but I just get errors. I need the final value the 1694 as a Float.

How do I do this?

Comment: You should [edit] your question with what you tried and what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CMTimeRange` is just that, a range of times. It has `start`, `end`, and `duration` properties. Each of those is a `CMTime`. `CMTime` has a `seconds` property as a `Double`.

```
if let range = AudioPlayerManager.shared.currentTrack?.playerItem?.loadedTimeRanges[0] {
    let seconds = Float(range.duration.seconds)
}
```

This will give you the number of seconds as a `Float`. Change `duration` to `end` if that's what you need.